# How do I convert "1.20E+07" to a float?

Tags: c#

I can't convert the text, "1.20E+07" to a float.

I've tried:

```
info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo ("en-US");
float.TryParse ("1.20E+07", NumberStyles.AllowExponent, info, out cellValue);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: you tried? and what was the result ?

Comment: It came out as a false in TryParse's result. Added the NumberStyle as below and ti works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also allow for decimal points like this

```
float.TryParse ("1.20E+07", NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, info, out cellValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NumberStyles.Float` instead, and it works. I just tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `NumberStyles.Float`.

(as documented under [float.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4.aspx), by the way :) )

Answer (score 1):

Even `NumberStyles.Any` worked for me